# Spread operator in Elm

Tags: list, elm

I want to show a select box's options from a list with 2 existing options.

What I want seems like this: (`spread operator` in JS)

```
select
  [ class "js-wlSize" ]
  [ option [ disabled True ] [ text "Choose size" ]
  , option [] [ text "Default size" ]
    ...( List.map (\s -> option [ value s ] [ text s] ) myListData )
  ]
```

I also tried with [( :: )](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#(::)), but It worked for 1 default option. I don't know how to work with 2 and more.

Can anyone know how to archive this in Elm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can chain the cons operator, e.g.:

```
1 :: 2 :: [ 3, 4, 5 ]
```

But if you have a list then the append operator, `++`, might be more appropriate:

```
[ 1, 2 ] ++ [ 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Note however that append is very inefficient on lists, especially compared to cons. Cons is O(1) while append is O(n), see [Why is appending to a list bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1320139/7943564). This is insignificant for small lists, but you might want to reconsider your approach if you find yourself wanting to use append on large lists.

Comment: How to determine whether a list is large or small (in respect to the above)?

Comment: That depends entirely on circumstance and constraints. Whether you're doing this just once, or in another loop that is `O(n)`, for example, which would make the whole algorithm `O(n^2)`. If in doubt, it's always best to measure.